After installed the network driver from realtek.com, UI isn't showing in the connections list

Ubuntu 24.04
KDE Plasma

I tried installing the network driver from realtek.com because my default network driver dropped a few seconds every 10-60 minutes. It now works after a full configuration in the terminal.
The networking is working. I see the net interface in ifconfig -a and ip a. It's UP, but I can't see it in the UI - KDE Network Connections.

Maybe it's available some way to create fake net, but I didn't find any option in KDE Network Connections settings.
How to add to KDE Network Connections my new network connection that was added my terminal commands and isn't showing in the UI?
At first I can't see it in the tray as an icon showing that the network is UP, and the network monitor is showing network activity as 0, but ifconfig is showing that my interface is UP and I see bytes that network processed.

additional info: nmcli say that all interfaces "unmanaged", is it possible to change it after new driver was installed?
